# How to increase PyTorch's AI's accuracy in image classifier?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, image-classification

I am trying to build a powerful image classifier.
But I have an issue. I use CIFRAS-100 dataset, and I trained a model from it.
Issue here that the correct classificatons are equal to 15%.
I tried continuing learn process, but after 2-3 attempts, model has not changed.

Code that I used for training:

````
import torch
import sys,os
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

batch_size = 4

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root='./dataone', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root='./dataone', train=False,
                                       download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                         shuffle=False, num_workers=2)
classes = ('aquatic mammals','fish','flowers','food containers','fruit and vegetables','household electrical devices','household furniture','insects','large carnivores','large man-made outdoor things','large natural outdoor scenes','large omnivores and herbivores','medium-sized mammals','non-insect invertebrates','people','reptiles','small mammals','trees','vehicles 1','vehicles 2')
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 100)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except batch
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
import torch.optim as optim
PATH = "./model.pt"
model = Net()
net = Net()
print(os.path.exists(PATH))
if os.path.exists(PATH):
    optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
    checkpoint = torch.load(PATH)
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state_dict'])
    optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state_dict'])
    epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
    loss = checkpoint['loss']
    print("using checkpoint")
    #model.eval()
    # - or -
    model.train()

#criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
#optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)import torch.optim as optim

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

for epoch in range(2):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
        inputs, labels = data

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        print("training..")
        # print statistics
        #running_loss += loss.item()
        #if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 mini-batches
        #    print(f'[{epoch + 1}, {i + 1:5d}] loss: {running_loss / 2000:.3f}')
        #    running_loss = 0.0

print('Finished Training')

#PATH = './cifar_net.pth'
#torch.save(net.state_dict(), PATH)

EPOCH = 5

LOSS = 0.4

torch.save({
            'epoch': EPOCH,
            'model_state_dict': net.state_dict(),
            'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
            'loss': LOSS,
            }, PATH)```
It's based on PyTorch tutorial about image cassifiers, that can be found [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html).
I took code for resuming training from [here.](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/saving_and_loading_a_general_checkpoint.html)

Code that I used for testing model:
````

import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

````
transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

batch_size = 4

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root='./dataone', train=False,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root='./dataone', train=False,
                                       download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                         shuffle=False, num_workers=2)
classes = ('aquatic mammals','fish','flowers','food containers','fruit and vegetables','household electrical devices','household furniture','insects','large carnivores','large man-made outdoor things','large natural outdoor scenes','large omnivores and herbivores','medium-sized mammals','non-insect invertebrates','people','reptiles','small mammals','trees','vehicles 1','vehicles 2')
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 100)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except batch
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x


net = Net()
PATH = './cifar_net.pth'
net.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
correct = 0
total = 0
# since we're not training, we don't need to calculate the gradients for our outputs
with torch.no_grad():
    for data in testloader:
        images, labels = data
        # calculate outputs by running images through the network
        outputs = net(images)
        # the class with the highest energy is what we choose as prediction
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
print(correct)
print(total)
print(f'Accuracy of the network on the 100000 test images: {100 * correct // total} %')```
````

It's from the same image classifier tutorial by PyTorch. I added printing total and correct detected images for testing.

How can I increase accuracy, so it will be at least around 50-70%?
Or is this normal, and it means that these 15% are incorrect?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the number of epochs? Training usually requires hundreds to thousands of iterations to obtain good results.

You could also improve the architecture by continuing the convolutional layers until you are left with a 1×1×N image where N is the number of filters in the final convolution. Then flatten and add linear layer(s). Batch Normalization and LeakyReLU activation before pooling layers may also help. Finally, you should use Softmax activation on the output since you are dealing with a classifier.

I highly recommend looking into popular classifiers such as VGG and ResNet. ResNet in particular has a feature called "residual/skip connections" that passes a copy of the output of a layer forward down the line to compensate for feature loss.

Comment: > Have you tried increasing the number of epochs? 
I tried resuming training 3 times, but no luck.
> You could also improve the architecture by continuing the convolutional layers until you are left with a 1×1×N image where N is the number of filters in the final convolution
I am new at using PyTorch or any other AI. Where I can modify that N number?

And lastly, how do I use softmax in PyTorch?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide accuracies and loss plots so we can understand better what is happening in the training (or maybe the list of accuracies and losses during training).

Also, it is a good practice to compute the validation accuracy and loss after every epoch to monitor the behaviour of the network on unseen data.

Although, as it has been said by Xynias, there are some improvements you could do on your architecture I believe the first step would be to investigate from the accuracies and losses.

Comment: Accuracy(in %): 15%
Correct classified images:1520
Total images: 10000
(I don't know why it's 10 000, it should be 100 000?)
In optimizer, lr equals to 0.001
But in other part of the code, running_loss = 0.0.
Why?

Comment: Have you read this ? https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html It is a base example for image classification from the Pytorch doc, and it is a very good starting point. It will give you a boilerplate code, and give you the base information on learning rate, batch size, ... I think you are confusing notions like lr and loss. About the test size, CIFAR-100 has a 10000 test size, not 100000.

Comment: Yep, I did. Code that I used is based on this tutorial's examples.
Also I've set amount of epochs to 50, now I need to wait approx. 3 days for training to finish.

Comment: After 3 days, nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Given CIFAR100 having 100 classes, this is expectable. You'll need a resonably complex network to perform well on this task. Definitely more feature maps, starting with 64 or more channels.

This Q&D architecture surpasses 50% overall accuracy after 10 epochs or so (using learning rate of 0.1 and batch size of 256, I also added `RandomHorizontalFlip()` transform):

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 128, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(128, 128, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.AvgPool2d(2, 2),
            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 256, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.AvgPool2d(2, 2),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Linear(16384, 100),
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layers(x)
```

For a better result you may try implementing something ResNet-like, or utilize a premade (and possibly pretrained) model, for example, using timm:

```
import timm
net = timm.create_model('resnet18d', pretrained=True, num_classes=100)
```

It achieves your target metrics pretty fast with the same parameters as above.

Comment: It crashed with error: `self.__class__.__name__, "\n\t".join(error_msgs)))
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Net:
        Missing key(s) in state_dict: "layers.0.weight", "layers.0.bias", "layers.2.weight", "layers.2.bias", "layers.5.weight", "layers.5.bias", "layers.7.weight", "layers.7.bias", "layers.12.weight", "layers.12.bias".
        Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "conv1.weight", "conv1.bias", "conv2.weight", "conv2.bias", "fc1.weight", "fc1.bias", "fc2.weight", "fc2.bias", "fc3.weight", "fc3.bias".`

Comment: Since the network structure is different, you should remove the old checkpoint (or comment out load_state_dict()).